# How to prove that pipeline in Redis is not atomic

Tags: redis

As we know, pipeline in Redis is not atomic. I want to make sure that with code. My code are like this:

```py
import redis
import threading

r1 = redis.Redis('127.0.0.1')

def get_incr(key, repeat=0):
  for i in range(repeat):
    get_return, incr_return = r1.pipeline().get(key).incr(key).execute()
    if int(incr_return) - int(get_return) != 1:
      print get_return, incr_return

threading.Thread(target=get_incr, args=('test',), kwargs=dict(repeat=10000)).start()
threading.Thread(target=get_incr, args=('test',), kwargs=dict(repeat=10000)).start()
```

I expect the console to print something but it didn't.

Comment: A pipeline of 2 is too small for the server to serve another client between the requests - try making it 100 or so.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using the [python client](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py).

This client's pipeline implementation is atomic by default, i.e. it wraps with `MULTI` and `EXEC` commands. In order to do your test, you need to disable the atomic feature:

```
pipe = r1.pipeline(transaction=False)
```

**UPDATE**

You can try the following code to do the test:

```
def get_func(key, repeat):
    r1 = redis.Redis('127.0.0.1')
    pipe = r1.pipeline(transaction=False)
    for j in range(repeat):
        pipe.get(key)
    res = pipe.execute()
    for j in range(repeat - 1):
        if res[j] != res[j + 1]:
            print('not atomic')

def incr_func(key, repeat):
    r1 = redis.Redis('127.0.0.1')
    pipe = r1.pipeline(transaction=False)
    for j in range(repeat):
        pipe.incr(key)
    pipe.execute()

threading.Thread(target=get_func, args=('test'), kwargs=dict(repeat=100000)).start()
threading.Thread(target=incr_func, args=('test'), kwargs=dict(repeat=100000)).start()
```

I'm not familiar with Python, if the code has bugs, feel free to correct me :)

Comment: This time I add (transaction=False), and also increase the concurrent threads to 100 as Itamar Haber points out. But the server still seems to execute the pipeline atomically :(

Comment: I think you misunderstand @ItamarHaber. You need to increase the number of commands in a pipeline, NOT the number of threads. See my update in the answer for an example.

Comment: @for_stack You should probably have a dedicated connection object per thread and not reuse the same one. I'm not a python expert, but I'm guessing that if it is threadsafe it will block and execute serially, and if it is not it will simply create a mess.

Comment: @OfirLuzon Thanks for your suggestion. I've updated the answer to create a dedicated Redis object in each thread.

Comment: @for_stack I saw the "not atomic" output with your code though it occurs occasionally. Thanks for your reply :) And I found it more easy to reproduce this when executing the INCR command in a [redis-cli](https://redis.io/topics/rediscli) during the "get" pipeline execution